# How to ignore channel entry in expressionEngine?

Tags: php, expressionengine

i have done dynamic entry in expression Engine.now i have problem with this because i want to show first four entry on first page and other entries on another page so how can i do this?

Comment: Apply Pagination for the entries

Answer (score 1):

If it's not [pagination](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/pagination_page.html) you're after, and you **specifically** want to have one page with 4, and the rest on another page, on the first page.

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="news" limit="4"}
<h2>{title}</h2>
{body}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

And then on the second page you use the [offset](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/channel_entries.html#offset) property to show the rest of the entries

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="news" offset="4"}
<h2>{title}</h2>
{body}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like

```
{exp:comment:entries channel="channelname" sort="asc" limit="4" paginate="bottom"}
    {paginate}
        {if previous_page}
            <a href="{auto_path}">Previous Page</a> &nbsp;
        {/if}
        {if next_page}
            <a href="{auto_path}">Next Page</a>
        {/if}
    {/paginate}
{/exp:comment:entries}
```